# How do I subtract the sum of the values of a Google spreadsheet column from a fixed number?

Tags: google-sheets

This question pertains to Google Sheets only.

How do I subtract the sum of the values of a Google spreadsheet column from a fixed number?

I want to subtract the sum of the numbers in column D a sheet from 26 000. Column D will be dynamic; new numbers will be added every day to it.

Comment: `=26000-sum(D:D)`

Answer (score 0):

If the values are in Column D, starting with row 5 (D5:D), then simply make a cell equal to your fixed number (or a reference to another cell) minus the sum of the values in your desired column. Here's what I wrote:

```
=26000-sum(D5:D)
```

Here's a link to a sample sheet so you can see it in action:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18TZPbvp4kqyYSe-fNH-6ByWh64Dl9QbECIGiCrSwLwM/edit#gid=0